# How can I convert Abstract Controls, namely FormGroups, into regular objects after passing them into a new SubjectBehavior object?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I am having a problem when after an Abstract Control is passed into the SubjectBehavior object, (in this case, a FormGroup) I am no longer able to retrieve any of the elements using .value. All of the arrays and groups and changed into empty or null values.

data.service.ts:

```
constructor() 
{
    // This is the Abstract Control
    var testObj = this.fb.group({"string":this.fb.array([this.fb.control('test')])});
    // All of the data in the control is preserved.
    console.log("debugRemove) testObj before BehaviorSubject", testObj.value);
    this.dataSource = new BehaviorSubject<Object>(testObj)
    this.currentData = this.dataSource.asObservable();
}

changeData() {
    this.dataJSON = await this.dataObject
    this.dataSource.next(data)
}
```

tables.component:

```
async ngOnInit() {
    await this.data.currentData.subscribe(data => {
        // data.value returns an empty object.
        console.log("data.value", data.value)

}
```

The console log shows that before the SubjectBehavior is created, the console shows the expected `Object` with all of its data: `testObj` before BehaviorSubject -

```js
Object { string: (1) string: Array [ "testData" ] }
```

Unfortunately, when the data appears in the subscribe function, I am unable to extract the data -- they all return empty or null values: data.value
Object {}

Comment: Since you typed your subject as `<Object>`, you should get error when trying to access the `.data` property in your subscribe.  But, if you just log `data` (instead of `data.value`) does an object get logged?

Comment: Holy moley, I think that's whats wrong. I'm not used to checking the type with the greater than/less than deals. To answer your question: Yes, sir, the data does get logged as a FormGroup...

Comment: I just checked it and changing it to FormGroup doesn't solve the problem. I read somewhere that FormGroup was discouraged for use outside of the components as it pertains to the UI, but this app I'm building seems to be complicated.

Comment: Alright! Good!!  :-) Also, I see you have ngOnInit marked as async... that doesn't really do anything.

Comment: LOL you other comment just popped up.  What do you mean it didn't solve the problem?  I thought you said the object is coming thorough?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229878/discussion-between-bizzybob-and-lester).

Comment: If you need to stream a `FormGroup` through a `BehaviorSubject`, rest assured you are doing it wrong, whatever it is you are trying to achieve.

Comment: As BizzyBob said, first of all you should remove the unnecessary async on ngOnInit and the await on the subscribe (it doesn't do anything and I don't even know how Angular handles that/if it even does). What IDE are you using thats not warning you about an unnecessary await? 

    ngOnInit() {
        this.data.currentData.subscribe(data => {
            // data.value returns an empty object.
            console.log("data.value", data.value)
    
    }
And I think you should post more of your code, because there are at least 2 variables missing which seem necessary to understand.